# SVG not showing after dynamicallly added into HTML document

Tags: javascript, html, svg, xslt-2.0, saxon

I am using Saxon CE for some transformations from xml to another xml and then to svg. My point is, that the transformations completes successfully and in source I am able to see that the svg has been added into the HTML document, however is not visible for some reason (I have set visibility to visible and that does not help). I am attaching the HTML structure as it before the transformations begins, then is the transformation output and finally the updated HTML. When I open the full HTML just in browser it works fine. Could it be some runtime problem i guess, however I do not know where to look for more information.

EDIT: I have previously used "g" elements, I thought it should be connected with it, but do not seems like it

```
<g>
```

Thanks in advance for any tips and help,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Book Catalogue</title>

    <script src="http://localhost:12345/SaxonCE/Saxonce.nocache.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function PK_func(in_xml) {
        var proc = Saxon.newXSLT20Processor(Saxon.requestXML("Flattening_XSD_StackOverFlow.xsl"));
        proc.transformToDocument(Saxon.parseXML(in_xml)); 
        var rd1URI = proc.getResultDocuments()[0];
        var rd1Doc = proc.getResultDocument(rd1URI);
        //var proc2 = Saxon.newXSLT20Processor(Saxon.requestXML("Flattening_XSD_StackOverFlow.xsl"));
        //proc2.updateHTMLDocument(Saxon.parseXML(in_xml)); 
        return rd1Doc;
}

function PK_func_2(in_xml) {
        var proc = Saxon.newXSLT20Processor(Saxon.requestXML("Visualise_flatten_xsd.xsl"));
        proc.transformToDocument(Saxon.parseXML(in_xml)); 
        var rd1URI = proc.getResultDocuments()[0];
        var rd1Doc = proc.getResultDocument(rd1URI);
        var proc2 = Saxon.newXSLT20Processor(Saxon.requestXML("Visualise_flatten_xsd.xsl"));
        proc2.updateHTMLDocument(rd1Doc); 
        return rd1Doc;
}

function get_width(input_text) {
    var measuringCanvas = document.getElementById('measuringCanvas');
    var ctx = measuringCanvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.font = "12px Verdana";
    var width = ctx.measureText(input_text).width;
    return width + 60;
}

window.onload = function() {
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
    fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        var file = fileInput.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e)
        {
            var xml = reader.result;
            var flatten_xsd = PK_func(xml);
            console.log(flatten_xsd);
            var visualised_xsd = PK_func_2(flatten_xsd);
            console.log(visualised_xsd);
        }
        reader.readAsText(file);
    });
}

</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="sortToolTip" class="tooltip" style="position:fixed; visibility:hidden; left:0px; top:0px">
    Click to sort on this column
</div>
<canvas id="measuringCanvas" display="none" width="50px" height="50px" style="display: none;"></canvas>
<h1 id="title">Header</h1>
<input type="file" id="fileInput">

<h2>Genres</h2>
<div id="genres"></div>

<h2>Books</h2>
<div id="XYZ"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

The added SVG:

```
<svg visibility="visible" height="500" width="500">
    <svg visibility="visible" transform="scale(37.03703703703704)">
        <rect style="fill: none; stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1" height="1" width="2" y="1" x="5.5"/>
        <line style="stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1;" y2="2.5" x2="6.5" y1="2" x1="6.5"/>
        <line style="stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1;" y2="2.5" x2="6.5" y1="2.5" x1="6.5"/>
        <line style="stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1;" y2="3" x2="6.5" y1="2.5" x1="6.5"/>
        <svg visibility="visible" pk:maxy="8" pk:maxx="12.5" pk:thisx="7.5">
            <rect style="fill: none; stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1" height="1" width="2" y="3" x="5.5"/>
            <line style="stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1;" y2="4.5" x2="6.5" y1="4" x1="6.5"/>
            <line style="stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1;" y2="4.5" x2="11.5" y1="4.5" x1="1.5"/>
            <line style="stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1;" y2="5" x2="1.5" y1="4.5" x1="1.5"/>
            <line style="stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1;" y2="5" x2="4" y1="4.5" x1="4"/>
            <line style="stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1;" y2="5" x2="6.5" y1="4.5" x1="6.5"/>
            <line style="stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1;" y2="5" x2="9" y1="4.5" x1="9"/>
            <line style="stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1;" y2="5" x2="11.5" y1="4.5" x1="11.5"/>

            <svg visibility="visible" pk:maxy="6" pk:maxx="2.5" pk:thisx="2.5">
                <rect style="fill: none; stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1;" height="1" width="2" y="5" x="0.5"/>
            </svg>

            <svg visibility="visible" pk:maxy="6" pk:maxx="5" pk:thisx="5">
                <rect style="fill: none; stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1;" height="1" width="2" y="5" x="3"/>
            </svg>

            <svg visibility="visible" pk:maxy="6" pk:maxx="7.5" pk:thisx="7.5">
                <rect style="fill: none; stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1;" height="1" width="2" y="5" x="5.5"/>
            </svg>

            <svg visibility="visible" pk:maxy="6" pk:maxx="10" pk:thisx="10">
                <rect style="fill: none; stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1;" height="1" width="2" y="5" x="8"/>
            </svg>
            <svg visibility="visible" pk:maxy="8" pk:maxx="12.5" pk:thisx="12.5">
                <rect style="fill: none; stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1" height="1" width="2" y="5" x="10.5"/>
                <line style="stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1;" y2="6.5" x2="11.5" y1="6" x1="11.5"/>
                <line style="stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1;" y2="6.5" x2="11.5" y1="6.5" x1="11.5"/>
                <line style="stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1;" y2="7" x2="11.5" y1="6.5" x1="11.5"/>

                <svg visibility="visible" pk:maxy="8" pk:maxx="12.5" pk:thisx="12.5">
                    <rect style="fill: none; stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1;" height="1" width="2" y="7" x="10.5"/>
                </svg>
            </svg>
        </svg>
    </svg>
</svg>
```

The final document (which is rendering "fine", at at least renders at all :)) :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Book Catalogue</title>
<script src="http://localhost:12345/SaxonCE/Saxonce.nocache.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script defer="defer">Saxonce.onInjectionDone('Saxonce')</script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function PK_func(in_xml) {
        var proc = Saxon.newXSLT20Processor(Saxon.requestXML("Flattening_XSD_StackOverFlow.xsl"));
        proc.transformToDocument(Saxon.parseXML(in_xml)); 
        var rd1URI = proc.getResultDocuments()[0];
        var rd1Doc = proc.getResultDocument(rd1URI);
        return rd1Doc;
}

function PK_func_2(in_xml) {
        var proc = Saxon.newXSLT20Processor(Saxon.requestXML("Visualise_flatten_xsd.xsl"));
        proc.transformToDocument(Saxon.parseXML(in_xml)); 
        var rd1URI = proc.getResultDocuments()[0];
        var rd1Doc = proc.getResultDocument(rd1URI);
        var proc2 = Saxon.newXSLT20Processor(Saxon.requestXML("Visualise_flatten_xsd.xsl"));
        proc2.updateHTMLDocument(rd1Doc); 
        return rd1Doc;
}

function get_width(input_text) {
    var measuringCanvas = document.getElementById('measuringCanvas');
    var ctx = measuringCanvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.font = "12px Verdana";
    var width = ctx.measureText(input_text).width;
    return width + 60;
}

window.onload = function() {
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
    fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        var file = fileInput.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e)
        {
            var xml = reader.result;
            var flatten_xsd = PK_func(xml);
            console.log(flatten_xsd);
            var visualised_xsd = PK_func_2(flatten_xsd);
            console.log(visualised_xsd);
        }
        reader.readAsText(file);
    });
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="sortToolTip" class="tooltip" style="position:fixed; visibility:hidden; left:0px; top:0px">
    Click to sort on this column
</div>
<canvas id="measuringCanvas" display="none" width="50px" height="50px" style="display: none;"></canvas>
<h1 id="title">Header</h1>
<input id="fileInput" type="file">

<h2>Genres</h2>
<div id="genres"></div>

<h2>Books</h2>
<div id="XYZ"></div>

<iframe tabindex="-1" style="position: absolute; width: 0px; height: 0px; border: medium none;" id="Saxonce" src="javascript:''"></iframe>
    <svg visibility="visible" height="500" width="500">
    <svg visibility="visible" transform="scale(37.03703703703704)">
        <rect style="fill: none; stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1" height="1" width="2" y="1" x="5.5"/>
        <line style="stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1;" y2="2.5" x2="6.5" y1="2" x1="6.5"/>
        <line style="stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1;" y2="2.5" x2="6.5" y1="2.5" x1="6.5"/>
        <line style="stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1;" y2="3" x2="6.5" y1="2.5" x1="6.5"/>
        <svg visibility="visible" pk:maxy="8" pk:maxx="12.5" pk:thisx="7.5">
            <rect style="fill: none; stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1" height="1" width="2" y="3" x="5.5"/>
            <line style="stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1;" y2="4.5" x2="6.5" y1="4" x1="6.5"/>
            <line style="stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1;" y2="4.5" x2="11.5" y1="4.5" x1="1.5"/>
            <line style="stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1;" y2="5" x2="1.5" y1="4.5" x1="1.5"/>
            <line style="stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1;" y2="5" x2="4" y1="4.5" x1="4"/>
            <line style="stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1;" y2="5" x2="6.5" y1="4.5" x1="6.5"/>
            <line style="stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1;" y2="5" x2="9" y1="4.5" x1="9"/>
            <line style="stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1;" y2="5" x2="11.5" y1="4.5" x1="11.5"/>

            <svg visibility="visible" pk:maxy="6" pk:maxx="2.5" pk:thisx="2.5">
                <rect style="fill: none; stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1;" height="1" width="2" y="5" x="0.5"/>
            </svg>

            <svg visibility="visible" pk:maxy="6" pk:maxx="5" pk:thisx="5">
                <rect style="fill: none; stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1;" height="1" width="2" y="5" x="3"/>
            </svg>

            <svg visibility="visible" pk:maxy="6" pk:maxx="7.5" pk:thisx="7.5">
                <rect style="fill: none; stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1;" height="1" width="2" y="5" x="5.5"/>
            </svg>

            <svg visibility="visible" pk:maxy="6" pk:maxx="10" pk:thisx="10">
                <rect style="fill: none; stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1;" height="1" width="2" y="5" x="8"/>
            </svg>
            <svg visibility="visible" pk:maxy="8" pk:maxx="12.5" pk:thisx="12.5">
                <rect style="fill: none; stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1" height="1" width="2" y="5" x="10.5"/>
                <line style="stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1;" y2="6.5" x2="11.5" y1="6" x1="11.5"/>
                <line style="stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1;" y2="6.5" x2="11.5" y1="6.5" x1="11.5"/>
                <line style="stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1;" y2="7" x2="11.5" y1="6.5" x1="11.5"/>

                <svg visibility="visible" pk:maxy="8" pk:maxx="12.5" pk:thisx="12.5">
                    <rect style="fill: none; stroke: black; stroke-width:0.1;" height="1" width="2" y="7" x="10.5"/>
                </svg>
            </svg>
        </svg>
    </svg>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you stack multiple `svg`s inside eachother?

Answer (score 0):

I have not checked all the script code but as you seem to create the SVG first as XML I would start first by ensuring that the SVG elements are in the SVG namespace and not in no namespace as in the sample you have shown.